# Question related to Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove or disprove: Let $D$ be an unbounded domain in $\mathbb{C}$. If $f$ is a bounded, analytic function on $D$, then must $f$ be constant on $D$?

This is clearly related to Liouville's Theorem, yet I am not sure how to approach this question using an arbitrary unbounded domain rather than all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You sound like you are trying to prove it. Have you also tried disproving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to try to show exactly why boundedness is essential for the function $f$. It's not really a disproof, but there have already been counter-examples given, and there's no reason to be redundant. Let's look at a proof of Liouville's Theorem (which can be found anywhere really, but this one comes from Brown and Church's book on elementary complex analysis), obviously with m own emphasis.

Theorem: If a function $f$ is entire and bounded on $\mathbb C$, then $f(z)$ is constant in the plane.

Proof: Since $f$ is entire, we can apply Cauchy's inequality with any $z_0$ we like and $R$ as the radius of the circle used as the contour in the inequality. By the deformation of paths principle, we can change the shape of this circle in to some contour so that it lies entirely in your unbounded region. In particular, since $n=1$ in the inequality, we know that

$$|f'(z_0)| \leq \frac{M_R} {R}$$

where $M_R$ is the maximal value attained on the contour.

$\color{red}{\text {However, since $f$ is bounded over all of $\mathbb C$, there is a constant $M$ which bounds this value for any $R$,}}$
 i.e. $R$ can be taken arbitrarily large, and $\frac{M_R}{R} \leq  \frac {M}{R}$, so replace $M_R$ with $M$ and observe that $M$ is now totally independent of $R$. But since $R$ can be arbitrarily large, we must have that $|f'(z_0)|=0$ everywhere. This implies that $f$ is constant, and we're done.

So the real trick here was to extend Cauchy's inequality, which is defined over a circle, to the whole complex plane. For this to be permissible, we can't have $f$ blow up as we go far away from the origin. As a last note, it should be clear that boundedness over $\mathbb C$ is not strictly necessary, but the boundedness of $f$ over your domain is absolutely essential.

Comment: The problem is you can't insure $|z-z_0|^2$ is uniformly large on these ever-lengthening contours, and that estimate was key for increasing concentric circles. For example, try it for $f'(0)$ in the strip $|\{x+iy: |y|<1\}.$ Whatever contour you try, there will some part of it within $1$ of $0.$

Comment: Why do I need it to be uniformly large when I know that $f$ is bounded? Perhaps there's something in the proof I don't understand.. o.O

Comment: The forumula is $f'(z_0) = (1/2\pi)\int_\gamma [f(z)/(z-z_0)^2]dz.$ If we try to copy the proof for the disc, we crash through with absolute values and get the esimate $$(1/2\pi)M(|\gamma|)/\inf|z-z_0|^2,$$ which does us no good unless that $\inf$ goes to $\infty,$ which is the same as saying we have arbitrarily large discs.

Comment: Does this actually answer what the OP is asking, which is about bounded functions on unbounded domains? Another example is that there are many bounded nonconstant analytic functions on $\{ z:|z|>1 \}$: $z^{-n}$, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Look at $e^z$ on $\{ z : \Re(z)<0\}$, for example. You'll find this function is bounded, analytic and nonconstant.

Comment: Thanks, this helps conceptualize the problem.